# How to avoid JQuery conflict with other library

Tags: jquery, core-ui

I am currently using [Core Ui Admin Template](https://coreui.io/docs/getting-started/introduction/#installation) in my Laravel 8 project.

On the installation part of **Core Ui** it needs these scripts.

```
script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"
script src= "https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui/dist/js/coreui.min.js"
```

I want to also use [Bootstrap's Tooltip](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/tooltips/). And I need to add a script to enable it.

```
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

$(window).on('load', function() { 
    $(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    })
});
```

My problem is that it doesn't work. And I have to leave out the **coreui.min.js script** for it to work. Any hint for this problem? TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```js
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function(tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new coreui.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@coreui/coreui@3.4.0/dist/js/coreui.bundle.min.js"></script>
<span class="d-inline-block" tabindex="0" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Disabled tooltip">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" style="pointer-events: none;" type="button" disabled>Disabled button</button>
</span>
```

Comment: It worked! I have also tried including popper.min.js using coreui.bundle.js both of them worked just fine. Thank you!

Comment: It was my pleasure to helping you.